# How to modify inner control property by setting container control dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, wpf-controls

I am creating a control in WPF which have inside a label and I have created a dependency property in order to modify the label's visibility property.

My problem is that I cant find a way to change my label's visibility property at the same time my dependency property is assigned.

My code  is as below:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty captionVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                                            "CaptionVisible",
                                                                            typeof(bool),
                                                                            typeof(MyCustomControl));

    public bool CaptionVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(captionVisibleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(captionVisibleProperty, value);
            ShowCaption();
        }
    }

    private void ShowCaption()
    {
        if (CaptionVisible)
        {
            captionLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            captionLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have tried to call my ShowCaption() method when my property is set, but nothing happens.

So, what I am supposed to do in order to get it done?

Hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem:

If you need to link a nested control dependency property to a container control dependency property you can do this:

```
     public static readonly DependencyProperty captionLabelVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                                                    "CaptionVisibility",
                                                                                    typeof(Visibility),
                                                                                    typeof(MyContainerControl),
                                                                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                                                                        VisibilityPropertyChangedCallback));

    public Visibility CaptionVisibility
    {
        get
        { return (Visibility)GetValue(captionLabelVisibilityProperty); }

        set
        { SetValue(captionLabelVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void VisibilityPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject controlInstance, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MyContainerControl myContainerControlInstance = (MyContainerControl)controlInstance;
        myContainerControlInstance.myLabel.Visibility = (Visibility)args.NewValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ShowCaption()` shouldn't be necessary.  Instead, just bind the label's `Visibility` property to your `CaptionVisible` property in xaml.  It's also best to follow the [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) design pattern for keeping your code organized.  This means putting the logic for controlling your user interface (the View) in separate ViewModel classes, and then assigning ViewModel to that View's `DataContext` property.

That will make the binding a lot easier. Referencing properties that belong to user interface elements can sometimes be a bit of a hassle in WPF.  By contract, WPF's bindings system was specifically designed to make it easy to get at the contents of a user interface element's `DataContext`.

You'll also need to use the handy-dandy `BooleanToVisiblityConverter` to make the binding  work, since the `Visibility` property's type isn't `bool`.  I like to put it in in the window's (or control's) resource dictionary for easy access:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>


<Label Visibility="{Binding Path=CaptionVisible, 
                            Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"> 
    <!-- label content -->
</Label>
```

As a side note, unless CaptionVisible is going to be the *target* of a binding, making it a dependency property is overkill.  In this binding it's only the source, so just implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` would be sufficient:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _captionVisible;
    public bool CaptionVisible
    {
        get { return _captionVisible; }
        set
        {
            if(_captionVisible != value)
            {
                _captionVisible = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CaptionVisible");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Sean U, But it did not work for me, actually I change the type of my property to Visibility but it still does not working

Comment: The bindings might not be working out quite right.  Have you seen any errors come up in the Output window while the program is running?

Comment: No, I have not, simple nothing happens. And since I changed the return type to "Visibility" I write this in the xaml file: Visibility="{Binding CaptionVisibility}", and I tried as well with Visibility="{Binding Path=CaptionVisibility}" but those did not work either

Comment: And what class does CaptionVisibility belong to?  If it's still in a control, then you need to also specify which control to look in for the binding.

Comment: The CaptionVisibility property and the label belongs to the same class since I am trying to develop my own control